# How to find attached disks are internal or external?

Tags: command-line, server, hardware, disk, disk-management

I used below command but it does not state whether the disk is internal or external.

```
$ lshw -C disk
```

Basically what I want to find out is whether the disk is coming from any external sources like SCSI or SAN or something like it, or whether it is a disk is installed on the server physically.

Thanks in Advance & apologize or poor english.

Comment: Is the `bus info` line in the output of `sudo lshw -c disk` for each device not helpful enough? Could you maybe list what kinds of buses your server has and which of them you consider to be externally/internally/both?

Comment: @Byte Commander: 
1) Anything over FC is external but some SCSI devices are local and some are external, hence need a better way to identify these things.
2) we have over 100 SCSI & FC LUN's per server & have 450 servers from where I need to capture this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on web searches, my first attempt was:

```
for dev in $(lsblk -ndo name)
do
    printf "$dev: "
    udevadm info --query property /dev/$dev | sed -n 's/ID_BUS=^//p'
done
```

which revealed that the external HDD I had plugged in by USB cable was marked as 'ata', not 'usb', as I expected. So I poked around the query output to find some other method, and came up with this:

```
for dev in $(lsblk -ndo name)
do
    udevadm info -q property /dev/$dev | 
        sed -n "s|^DEVPATH=|$dev/|p" |
        cut -d/ -f1,6 | tr / :
done
```

Based on the output in *my specific configuration*, I then ended up writing this Bash function:

```
is-internal-disk(){
    case $(udevadm info -q path $1 | cut -d/ -f5)
        ata*) return true ;;
        *)    return false ;;
    esac
}
```

I trust this to be reliable, because `udevadm` shows the property for every disk, and it *seems* pretty safe to assume that the fifth field always has the answer (I hope someone could comment on that).

If you want to know which external device is a mere memory stick (not HDD or SSD), you need yet another method, but I am not sure which of these two is better in the long run:

```
is-memory-stick(){
#   udevadm info -q property $1 | grep -q '^ID_BUS=usb$'
    udevadm info -q property $1 | grep -q '^ID_DRIVE_THUMB=1$'
}
```